# Selecting a random word from a list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get my macro(next word) to select a random word from a list and then another macro(definition) does a vlookup to return the definition. When I select the macro to grab a new word I need it to clear the macro for the definition so that I cant see it until i select the definition button. Right now i get  runtime error 1004 and it highlights my .clearcontent code at the end.

[image]

```
Sub showRandomWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, dataCol As Long
Dim dispRow As Long, dispCol As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
stRow = 2
dataCol = 1
dispRow = 2
dispCol = 2

With ws
    endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
End With
ws2.Cells(dispRow, dispCol).Value = 
ws.Cells(Application.RandBetween(stRow, endRow), dataCol).Value

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J2").ClearContents

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MergeArea`?

```
Sub showRandomWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, dataCol As Long
Dim dispRow As Long, dispCol As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
stRow = 2
dataCol = 1
dispRow = 2
dispCol = 2

With ws
    endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
End With

ws2.Cells(dispRow, dispCol).Value = ""
ws.Cells(Application.RandBetween(stRow, endRow), dataCol).Value

ws2.Range("J2").MergeArea.ClearContents

End Sub
```